# How would you translate this into data.table package language in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to learn `data.table` package in `R`. I have a data table named `DT1` and a data frame `DF1`, and I'd like to subset some instances according to a logical condition (disjunction). This is my code for now:

```
DF1[DF1$c1==0 | DF1$c2==1,] #the data.frame way with the data.frame DF1
DT1[DT1$c1==0 | DT1$c2==1,] #the data.frame way with the data.table DT1
```

On page 5 of ["Introduction to the data.table package in R"](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf), the author gives an example of something similar but with a conjuction (replace `|` by `&` in the second line above) and remarks that's a bad use of `data.table` package. He suggests todo it this way instead:

```
setkey(DT1,c1,c2)
DT1[J(0,1)]
```

So, my question is: How can I write the disjunction condition with the `data.table` package syntax? Is it a misuse my second line `DT1[DT1$c1==0 | DT1$c2==1,]`? Is there an equivalent to the `J` but for disjunction?

Answer (score 4):

That document indicates that you could have used:

```
DT1[c1==0 | c2==1, ]
```

Comment: I think your answer is still vector scan. Thanks anyway @DWin!

Comment: Yes that's 3 vector scans (two `==` and one `|`) plus associated vector allocations as described in intro vignette. That document shows something similar to demonstrate _bad_ use not good use. @Nestorghh But did you really mean disjoint across two columns (`c1` and `c2`)? Disjoint within a column is Christoph's answer: `J(c(0,1))`. Disjoint across two columns is vector scan for now until secondary keys are built in, or search for "manual secondary key" for a more onerous method in the meantime.

Comment: I did see that it was called "bad" practice, but I did not see an example of "correct use" that would apply in this two column case, nor did I find one in the FAQ, nor in searching the archives, nor in several attempts at experimentation.

Comment: You're right, but I was more responding to the first sentence of the answer. It might give the impression that the vignette encourages that idiom, or already had the answer which the OP missed. In fact the answer repeats (without the two `DT$`) the solution the OP put in the question and said he was (correctly) worried about.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution:

```
grpsize = ceiling(1e7/26^2)
DT <- data.table(
  x=rep(LETTERS,each=26*grpsize),
  y=rep(letters,each=grpsize),
  v=runif(grpsize*26^2))

setkey(DT, x)
system.time(DT1 <- DT[x=="A" | x=="Z"])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.68    0.05    0.74 
system.time(DT2 <- DT[J(c("A", "Z"))])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.08    0.00    0.07 
all.equal(DT1[, v], DT2[, v])
TRUE
```

Note that I took the example from the data.table document. The only difference is that I do not convert the letters into factors anymore because character keys are now allowed (see [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) for v 1.8.0).

A short explanation: `J` is just short for `data.table`. So if you call `J(0, 1)` you create a `data.table` with two columns that match, just like in the example:

```
> J(0,1)
     V1 V2
[1,]  0  1
```

You, however, want to match two different elements in one column. Therefore, you need a `data.table` with one column. So just add `c()`.

```
J(c(0,1))
     V1
[1,]  0
[2,]  1
```

Comment: +1. But OP needs to clarify: did he really mean disjoint across two columns (`c1` and `c2`)?  This answer is good for disjoint within one column.

Comment: @MatthewDowle Right, I missed that...I guess the OP meant actually disjoint across two columns.

Comment: @MatthewDowle & @Christoph_J, I meant disjoint across two columns ``c1`` and ``c2`` of my ``data.table`` ``DT1``. Do I have to do it in the vector scan way then? Thanks

Comment: @Nestorghh Yes but there are some other options e.g. manual secondary key. See comment in other question. If you get stuck on that then let us know. Search on datatable-help archive  for "manual secondary key".